# How to set View's (not TextView's) maximum width programmaticaly?

Tags: android, view

I have a popup View which should be placed to right of some other "anchor" views.
I'm using Android's `PopupWindow` with some location (calculated to be on right side of the anchor view).

If it's small, everything's ok, but when the popup view is very large, it ignores the given location and covers the anchor view. I'm wondering how can I prevent this and make the popup window to be as big as it's content, but not bigger than distance between given location and screen's right edge (let's call it available space).

This could be fixed by setting content's maximum width to available space before showing the popup window but only TextView has this property.

I can force measure the content and change the width if it's bigger than the available space, but I believe there's a better way I can't find out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your view in a layout and in the code set

> wraplayout.getLayoutParams().height = height;

and

> wraplayout.getLayoutParams().width = width;